# How to pass varible or data through components in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Hello , i am novice with react. So i want to pass data through components . i want to send the NavBar.js "state" variable to the home.js "loca" variable. Is it possible and how to send?**

Here is the App.js file

```js
<Router>
    <div className="App">
        <NavBar></NavBar>
        <div className="component">
            <Switch>
                <Home></Home>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Here is the NavBar.js

```js
    const NavBar = () => {
        const [getState, setGetState] = useState('London');
        const [state, setState] = useState('London');
    
        const inputHandler = (event) => {
            setGetState(event.target.value);
          };
          
        const submitHandler = () => {
            setState(getState);
        };
    
        return ( 
            <nav className="navbar">
                <Link className="nlink" to="/">Weather Portal</Link>
                <div className="links d-block">
                    <div className="col-auto">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="location-name"
                        className="form-control"
                        onChange={inputHandler}
                        value={getState} placeholder='Enter the location'
                    />
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary mt-2" onClick={submitHandler}>
                        Search
                    </button>              
                </div>
            </nav>
         );
    }
```

Here is the Home.js

```js
    const Home = () => {
        
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
        const loca = 'New York';
        
        useEffect(() => {
            const apiKey;
            const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${loca}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;
    
            fetch(url)
        },[])
    
        return ( 
            <div className="home">
                { data && <WeatherData datas={data} loca={loca}></WeatherData> } 
            </div>
      

   );
}
```

I want to send the NavBar.js `state` variable to the `home.js` `loca` variable. Is it possible and how to send?

Comment: This smells like a take home test, to be honest. Could you put what you have up on https://stackblitz.com? React has a "unidirectional data flow" architecture - it's central to the whole concept of building with react - data starts in some component and then "flows down" to the rest of the components in the tree underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

There are three Ways to pass data.

1. Redux
2. Context
3. Component Props

you can create listener in App.js file so once you submit from Nav then event will trigger in App.js and you will get value in App.js file and then you can send it to home component.

/*App.js*/

```
Class App{
const receivedValue= (NavData) => {
 console.log("Nav data",NavData);
} 
render(){
 return(
<Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar sendValues={this.receivedValues}></NavBar>
        <div className="component">
          <Switch>
            <Home></Home>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
);
}


}
```

/*Nav.js*/

```
Class Nav{

render(){
 return(
   <div>
     <a onClick={this.props.sendValues(this.state)}>
   </div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You need to render Home component according to the value of `state` being set in `NavBar` component by a form submit :-) .

inside App.jsx maintain a current_location as a state

```
const [current_state, setCurrentState] = useState('London')
```

then pass the `setCurrentState` function as a property to `NavBar` component

```
<NavBar set_current_state={setCurrentState}></NavBar>
```

And Your `NavBar` should be modified as

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
    ........
    const submitHandler = () => {
        setState(getState);
        props.set_current_state(getState)
    };
    ........
}
```

By this You are calling the `setCurrentState` method in `App` component thereby changing `current_state` which is a state variable.

Finaly You need to render `Home` as the state `current_state` changes. For that declare `Home` with passing `current_state` as prop, so that `Home` will re render when `set_current_state` is called from `NavBar`

```
<Home loca={current_state} />
```

Finally

```
const Home = (props) => {
    ......
    use props.loca instead of loca
    ......
}
```